# itween not working in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sprite called balloon. I want to move this balloon after destroying the enemy. This code is working fine but after destroying the enemy, it is not working.  Any ideas why?

```
public Vector3 position_store;
public Transform[] myPath;
public GameObject gameObject1;
public float x,y,z;
void Update () 
{
  if (destroyObject1 == true && destroyObject12==false) {
    iTween.MoveTo(gameObject,iTween.Hash("path",iTweenPath.GetPath("neck1"),"time",30));
}
}
```

Comment: where is attached this script? on ballon gameobject? your calling on itween gameobject, not your public gameobject1, and this is working over the attached script gameobject.

Comment: i attached this script on ballon game object.

Comment: you check that you enter on the condition? The iTween.moveto are ok.
The problem is in another place i think.